# Error resolving template on deploy jar or war on spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, jar, war

when i run my application on embedded tomcat server all thing is good.
but when i deploy jar or war on other server or container, server on some url give me error:
Error resolving template "/shop/index", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

this is my application.yml:

```
    server:
  port: 8080
logging:
    level:
        com.mousavi007.shop: debug
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shop2
    username: *******
    password: *******
    platform: mysql
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    database: mysql
    show-sql: true
  thymeleaf:
      mode: LEGACYHTML5
```

shop controller:

```
@Slf4j
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/shop")
public class ShopController {

@GetMapping({"","/"})
    public String Shop(Model model, @RequestParam("pageSize") Optional<Integer> pageSize,
                       @RequestParam("page") Optional<Integer> page){
**** 
****
****
****
            return "/shop/index";
}
}
```

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

change

```
return "/shop/index";
```

to

```
return "shop/index";
```

Comment: i change code and in jar mode all thing are ok. but in war mode give me error : Error resolving template "shop/index", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Comment: please check when you return "shop/index"; in which directory it searches for the file template.

Comment: How do I do this؟

Comment: when i deploy my app on linux container give me error but when i deploy on tomcat on windows all things is ok.